# C# How to implement dash "-" options in a command line argument?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, command-line, console

My C# classes will create a GUI that takes in csv files and plot a line graph accordingly. Currently, my graphs are plotted and saved using the GUI file dialog.

What I am trying to do now is to **read, plot and save** the graph using command-line instead (NO GUI needed).

May I know how could I call my Read and Plot classes using the "-f" flag (file path, can have multiple csv file) and save the plotted graph using the "-o" flag (output file path, only 1 file produced)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

**class Program:**

```
static class Program
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")] // ### Edit 3 ###
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId); // ### Edit 3 ###

    /// <summary>The main entry point for the application.</summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // redirect console output to parent process;
        // must be before any calls to Console.WriteLine()
        AttachConsole(-1);// ### Edit 3 ###

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //program.exe -f c:\\desktop\\1.csv -o c:\\desktop\\1.png
        var inputFile = new List<string>();
        string outputFile = null;

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                string a = args[i].ToLower();
                switch (a)
                {
                    case "-f":
                        for (i = i + 1; i < args.Length ; i++)
                        {
                            string f = args[i]; if (f.StartsWith("-")) { i--; break; }
                            inputFile.Add(f); //get next arg as inputFile
                        }
                        break;

                    case "-o":
                        outputFile = args[++i]; //get next arg as outputFile
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (inputFile.Count > 0 && outputFile != null)
            {
                var form = new Form2(); //specify your form class
                form.showErrorsInConsole = true; // ### Edit 3 ###
                //form.Visible = true;
                form.DoReadFiles(inputFile.ToArray());
                form.DoPlot();
                form.SavePic(outputFile);
                form.Dispose();
                return;
            }
        }
        //else
        Application.Run(new Form2()); //show GUI

        //MessageBox.Show("Args:\r\n" + s);

    }
}
```

**Form class** (the form conatining your chart, in my code it is Form2):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    List<Read> rList = new List<Read>();
    public bool showErrorsInConsole = false; //### Edit 3 ###

    public void DoReadFiles(string[] fileNames)
    {
        try
        {
            rList.Clear();
            foreach (String file in fileNames) //if ((myStream = ff.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                Read r = new Read(file);
                rList.Add(r);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //Inform the user if we can't read the file
            if (showErrorsInConsole) //### Edit 3 ###
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n *** Error: " + err.Message); //### Edit 3 ###
            else 
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    public void DoPlot(int indX = 0, int indY = 1)
    {
        Plot.Draw(chart, rList, indX, indY);

    }

    public void SavePic(string outputFile)
    {
        bool isPng = outputFile.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        chart.SaveImage(outputFile, isPng ? ChartImageFormat.Png : ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ff = new OpenFileDialog();

        ff.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); //"C:\\";
        ff.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        ff.Multiselect = true;
        ff.FilterIndex = 1;
        ff.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (ff.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                DoReadFiles(ff.FileNames);

                //Populate the ComboBoxes
                if (rList.Count > 0)
                {
                    string[] header = rList[0].header; //header of first file
                    xBox.DataSource = header;
                    yBox.DataSource = header.Clone(); //without Clone the 2 comboboxes link together!
                }
                if (yBox.Items.Count > 1) yBox.SelectedIndex = 1; //select second item
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Inform the user if we can't read the file
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoPlot(xBox.SelectedIndex, yBox.SelectedIndex);

    }

} //end class Form2
```

**class Read:**

```
public class Read
{
    public int nLines { get; private set; }
    public int nColumns { get; private set; }
    public string[] header { get; private set; }
    public float[,] data { get; private set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string[] section { get; private set; }

    public Read(string file)
    {
        string[] pieces;

        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);  
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file); // read all lines
        if (lines == null || lines.Length < 2) return; //no data in file
        header = lines[0].Split(','); //first line is header
        nLines = lines.Length - 1; //first line is header
        nColumns = header.Length;

        //read the numerical data and section name from the file
        data = new float[nLines, nColumns - 1]; // 1 less than nColumns as last col is sectionName
        section = new string[nLines];
        for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i++) 
        {
            pieces = lines[i + 1].Split(','); // i(+1) is because first line is header
            if (pieces.Length != nColumns) { MessageBox.Show("Invalid data at line " + (i + 2) + " of file " + fileName); return; }
            for (int j = 0; j < nColumns - 1; j++)
            {
                float.TryParse(pieces[j], out data[i, j]); //data[i, j] = float.Parse(pieces[j]);
            }
            section[i] = pieces[nColumns - 1]; //last item
        }
    }

}
```

**class Plot:**

```
public class Plot
{
    public static void Draw(Chart chart, List<Read> rList, int indX = 0, int indY = 1)
    {

        chart.Series.Clear(); //ensure that the chart is empty
        chart.Legends.Clear();
        Legend myLegend = chart.Legends.Add("myLegend");
        myLegend.Title = "myTitle";

        Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Magenta, Color.DarkCyan, Color.Chocolate, Color.DarkMagenta }; 
        var sectionColors = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        bool separateSections = (rList.Count == 1); // #Edit: 4

        int i = 0;
        int iColor = -1, maxColor = -1;
        foreach (Read rr in rList)
        {
            float[,] data = rr.data;
            int nLines = rr.nLines;
            int nColumns = rr.nColumns;
            string[] header = rr.header;

            chart.Series.Add("Series" + i);
            chart.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            chart.Series[i].LegendText = rr.fileName; // #Edit: 4
            if (separateSections) chart.Series[i].IsVisibleInLegend = false; // #Edit: 4

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{F2}";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = header[indX];
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = header[indY];

            for (int j = 0; j < nLines; j++)
            {
                int k = chart.Series[i].Points.AddXY(data[j, indX], data[j, indY]);
                if (separateSections) // #Edit: 4
                {
                    string curSection = rr.section[j];
                    if (sectionColors.ContainsKey(curSection))
                    {
                        iColor = sectionColors[curSection];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        maxColor++;
                        iColor = maxColor; sectionColors[curSection] = iColor;
                    }
                    chart.Series[i].Points[k].Color = colors[iColor];
                }
            }

            i++; //series#

        } //end foreach rr

        //fill legend based on series
        foreach (var x in sectionColors)
        {
            string section = x.Key;
            iColor = x.Value;
            myLegend.CustomItems.Add(colors[iColor], section); //new LegendItem()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I read the files and plot the graph in this case ? Since its not using the Read or Plot classes

Comment: 1 small question, how do I add the checking part if the input file does not exist, printout error? Thanks

Comment: Updated to show errors in console output. the edits are indicated by `//### Edit 3 ###` symbol in Program and Form classes

Comment: Hi S.Serp, now I would need to modify the code a little bit. Currently, if i would to input only 1 csv file, the graph and legends will show different colors based on their section names, which is correct. But now I would need to make it such that, if the input file is more than 1 csv, the colors/legend of the graph will only show 1 color for each file, e.g. 2 input file = 2 colors, legends will only show 2 colors based on the csv file name itself.

Comment: Hi. Its weekend here today and tomorrow. Couldn't you try to modify the code yourself? You may use a bool var to indicate its 2 file or more and doesn't change the colors in plot...

Comment: Hi, really sorry for troubling you. I've tried editing it myself but it did not work. You could help me when you have the time, not an urgent matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have posted edit #4 to reflect your request. there is 4 minor changes in `Plot` class indicated by `// #Edit: 4`

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot once again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something simple then you can just have a loop and get the values like this:

```
string f=null;
string o=null;
for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
{
    if (args[i] == "-f") { f = args[i + 1]; }
    else if (args[i] == "-o") { o = args[i + 1]; }
}

if (f != null)
{

}

if (o != null)
{

}
```

Comment: Just updated my code above. Will give your code a try later. Seems simple to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use command parser libraries. Command Line Parser ( http://commandline.codeplex.com/ ) is very easy to use.

```
[Option("f", "input", Required = true]
public string InputFile { get; set; }
[Option("o", "output", Required = true]
public string OutputFile { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there other way without using the command parser libraries? It seems quite complicated for me.